# how to execute chef-client parallelly in all chef nodes

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I have 20 nodes I want to run `chef-client` in all 20 nodes at the same time.
How can I achieve this?

What is [`knife ssh`](https://docs.chef.io/knife_ssh.html)?
If the above mentioned problem can be achieved using `knife ssh`: Can you please give examples to use?

Comment: You could just have read the docs or tried `knife ssh` prior to asking here..

Answer (score 2):

You could just have tried it... The easiest way is really [`knife ssh`](https://docs.chef.io/knife_ssh.html):

```
knife ssh '*:*' sudo chef-client
```

Other options also exist, including [Chef Push Jobs](https://docs.chef.io/push_jobs.html) or other standalone solutions like [Rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) (probably).